# Definite/indefinite article usage in literature

Tags: articles

Could you please help to understand the following sentence's grammar:

> Now, I'll fetch the wood and the coals, and you get a duster, Mole —
> you'll find one in the drawer of the kitchen table

(Kenneth Grahame: *The Wind in the Willows*, ch. 5)

Why '**a** duster' but '**the** wood' and '**the** coals'?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guessed that this was from *The Wind in the Willows*, which you should have told us.

Ratty has already stated his intention of lighting a fire, so he refers to *the* fuel which he will need to do so. Presumably there is more than one duster in the house, and it doesn't matter which one Mole uses.